# R covert values in rows with string of multiple values to columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this {each row in B is a string with values joined with $ symbol}:

```
A B
a 1$2$3
b 2$4$5
c 3$2$5
```

Now I want something like this{I want to create columns which say that the value is present in that row(of column B) or not.}:

```
A B     1 2 3 4 5
a 1$2$3 1 1 1 0 0
b 2$4$5 0 1 0 1 1
c 3$5   0 0 1 0 1
```

I want to do this **without using any loops in R**. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: any attempt from ur side?

Comment: Yeah I did it with loops already : 


   for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 lst = strsplit(as.character(df$B[i]), '\\$') [[1]]
 for(j in 1:length(lst)){
  df[i,lst[j]] = 1
 }
    }
    df[is.na(df)] = 0

But wanted an effective code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another attempt. First, I get all the unique values across the `B` column and then combine `table` with `factor` while specifying these levels for all the splits of the `B` column (edited after some comments from @akrun)

```
temp <- strsplit(as.character(df$B), "\\$") # Save the split column 
lvls <- unique(unlist(temp)) # Get unique values
df[lvls] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = lvls))))
df

#   A     B 1 2 3 4 5
# 1 a 1$2$3 1 1 1 0 0
# 2 b 2$4$5 0 1 0 1 1
# 3 c 3$2$5 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would to split the "B" column by `$` into a `list`, convert the `character` class to `numeric`, `stack` the `list` to a `data.frame`, change the 'ind' column to `numeric`, using `sparseMatrix` we convert it to binary matrix and then `cbind` with the original dataset to get the expected output.

```
 lst <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$B), "[$]"), as.numeric)
 df2 <- stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)))
 df2$ind <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$ind))
 library(Matrix)
 cbind(df1, as.matrix(sparseMatrix(df2$ind, df2$values, x=1)))
 #  A     B 1 2 3 4 5
 #1 a 1$2$3 1 1 1 0 0
 #2 b 2$4$5 0 1 0 1 1
 #3 c 3$2$5 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: An interesting approach. I"ll need to take a look in to the Matrix package some day...

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(mydf, "B", "$", fill = 0)
#   A     B B_1 B_2 B_3 B_4 B_5
# 1 a 1$2$3   1   1   1   0   0
# 2 b 2$4$5   0   1   0   1   1
# 3 c 3$2$5   0   1   1   0   1
```

Or, `mtabulate` from "qdapTools":

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(mydf, mtabulate(strsplit(mydf$B, "\\$")))
#   A     B 1 2 3 4 5
# 1 a 1$2$3 1 1 1 0 0
# 2 b 2$4$5 0 1 0 1 1
# 3 c 3$2$5 0 1 1 0 1
```